# sbrk под виндой

Tags: c

разбираю последние страницы K&R . тут они велосипедят , а именно описывают функцию malloc , free.
однако используют системный вызов sbrk , но пишут, что sbrk это системный вызов Юникс.
Вопрос , а в виндах такого нет - sbrk?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27802882/13970074

Comment: В учебных целях вы легко можете смоделировать `sbrk()` в любой ОС на достаточно большом статическом массиве

Comment: @АндрейГуренков используйте собаку + ник, чтобы участнику пришло уведомление

Comment: @avp массив из чего сделать ? из unsigned char ???

Comment: Без разницы. unsigned char тоже подойдет. Только возвращайте всегда адреса, кратные 8, чтобы проблем с выравниванием типов (например, double) в возвращаемой памяти не было

Comment: @avp вернусь к этому вопросу обязательно.